# Android static background options for game

Tags: android

I am trying to display a static background image (sort of the backdrop of an app) and have found that this can be done either by using the "android:background" option in my FrameLayout OR within the onDraw() method where this is done via the canvas.drawBitmap() at every entry.

Could someone please explain the difference between using these approaches and which offers better performance?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<resources>
    <style parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar" name="Theme.BG">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_image</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I wrote a style with this attribute and applied to the whole application via the manifest.
I extended the NoTitleTheme, You can extend any of the default themes in android

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.BG" android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:icon="@drawable/app_iconicon">
```

This is easily the most efficient way to apply a background to the whole app..

Setting the background to each Framelayout means writing more of code. And doing it in the onDraw requires you to extend a view or any other component. You can set teh background by these methods but the window background of the app is still drawn. But when you set the window backgorund like above, the default background is not drawn, and possibly you save the complexity of writing more code.

Comment: Hmmm... thanks. But wouldn't this apply to the background of whole app? i.e. if there were to be multiple activities wouldn't this apply to all of them? (sorry if this is a noob question)

Comment: Yes ofcourse, this would apply to the whole app i.e to all the activities.. If you want this to be applied to particular activities then you can simply place theme attribute to the requires <activity> instead of the <application> in the manifest

Comment: Ok got it (only looked at the Manifest after I read that :# ). So is there anyway to measure the difference in performance with each option?

Comment: There might not be a drastic difference as I believe that the default windowBackground that android draws is only Black Color. But yes, if you are using multiple acitivities then ther is surely a performance improvement as I believe that the bitmap doesnt need to be decoded/loaded into memory multiple times. And talking about measireing the memory usage may be u can use the tools provided with the SDK, im still learning to effieciently use those :)